# Working with nested Roles & Permissions in React Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

My question is more of how are you getting the list of roles for your React app for an app where a user might have a nested set of roles and permissions.  Are you sending the entire permission list/tree for the user up front when they log in and then stashing that so you can iterate it thereafter?

For example lets say a user is in Role 1 and Role 1 has a set of permissions, but they are also in several other roles or there might even be sub roles inside a role.  Are you basically getting that list up front and storing it in redux store?

So 2 questions:

**1)** *When and how are you getting the list of roles & permissions* (when, they log in?  What are you calling, a permissions endpoint or is it coming back in the session response payload when they log in? or some other way?)

**2)** *How are you storing and iterating that list?*

There are things you need to do on the UI side with a list like this such as hide/show delete buttons, hide/show whatever for a user based on certain roles & permissions so I'm wondering how people are doing this.

The backend API you hit, also checks that the user can perform whatever http verb but that's not what I'm referring to here, I am referring to traversing and checking roles on the UI side to handle user behavior / UI components behavior.  Some of that can be handled by finding out if a user can or can't succeed in an API call to a backend REST API but it goes much more beyond this if you have a complex set of roles, you still need to have that list up front somehow to do some up front behavior when a user lands on a component for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build permissions already merged from possible multiple roles on the server side having e.g. a structure like:

```
{
  "posts": ["add", "view"],
  "comments": ["add", "view", "delete", "change"]
}
```

When to send it hardly depends on the design of your app. As a response to login totally makes sense. The key point is that data is available before a component needs it. Then i would store these permissions in the redux store and connect the relevant components, e.g. like:

```js
const Comments = ({comments, hasDeletePermission, hasChangePermissions}) => {
  <ul>
    {comments.map(comment => (
      <li>
        <p>{comment}</p>      
        {hasChangePermission && <button>change</button>}
        {hasDeletePermission && <button>delete</button>}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  hasDeletePermission: state.user.permissions['comments'].includes('delete'),
  hasChangePermissions: state.user.permissions['comments'].includes('change'),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Comments);
```

You can also have default permission values for anonymous users.

Comment: Yea so you are getting the list of roles up front from the backend which is really what I was eluding to

Comment: And yea we would just get that list up front from the session loving response.  We have a session endpoint I hit and we would just return the permissions as a node of the returned session response json

Comment: @PositiveGuy Sound reasonable.

Comment: Just a quick tip: if you use numbers as values for the permissions, it's really easy to combine and filter them. E.g. VIEW=1, ADD=2, EDIT=4, DELETE=8. Then you can set them like this: `"posts": VIEW | ADD`. And filter like this `if(posts & VIEW) //show posts`

Comment: @trixn
Consider a case where the permission is provided from backend after successful login and user is redirected to the home page. After landing on the home page if the user refreshes the page then the permission stored in the redux store will be deleted, what to do in that case?

Comment: @Niraj The permissions stored in the redux store are just a description of entity level permissions the (already authenticated) user has. If you reload the app, the permissions have to be fetched again. If you redirect the user to the home page initially this has to be fetched anyways. You would probably have an end point for the user where the app can fetch user details including his/her permissions. The actual checking of permissions always happens on the server. The permissions stored in the front end are just for displaying purposes, e.g. displaying a certain action button or not.

Comment: @trixn Yes correct permissions are a description of object level. 
The permission has to be fetched, means i need to call permission on every route? 
I do have an API which provides permission based on the user id. In the backend, there is a second check to perform action only if allowed.

Comment: @Niraj If your app is a single-page-application you only need to fetch when the app loads. Route changes in the application will not wipe your redux store. If you have multiple apps for lets say every page then yes you will have to fetch them again. You could do that as a default step when initializing your react app. We usually provide a `/me` endpoint that returns the details about the authenticated user that does the request. There is no need to pass the id unless you want the user to be able to fetch details of users other then him/herself.

Comment: @Niraj There may be some edge cases where e.g. the permissions where changed while the user is working with the app. Therefore you need to gracefully handle denied permission errors. Because this should usually be a rare case I consider it sufficient to show an error and let the user reload the permissions. Also you could persist parts of the redux store in e.g. local storage. But then you need to have an invalidation strategy for changing permissions.

Comment: @Niraj Also you could fetch the permissions based on the currently rendered app route. It heavily depends on the size of your app and the use case. There is not a single best practice for that.

Comment: @trixn Yes the store persists on SPA but what if user explicitly reloads?
For making the store persistent i know some of the solutions but i don't want to go into that complexity. I have single app and not multiple.
Also the permissions were changed while the user is working with the app will not be edge case in my use case. So i am thinking to call my permission API on every route change so that u will be updated as the route changes. Not sure if this is right or not!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197553/discussion-between-niraj-and-trixn).